# How can I reuse a function in react/redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a link that saves the page.

```
    <Link
      onClick={this.savePDF}
      button="secondary" >
      Save as PDF
    </Link>
```

I have a save function that is being reused

```
save = (page) => () => {
  this.props.toggleSaving();
  this.props.savePage(page);
  this.props.toggleSaving();
};

 savePDF = (page) => {
  this.props.toggleSaving();
  this.props.savePage(page);
  this.props.toggleSaving();
  window.open(`${window.location.pathname}/print`, '_blank');
 };
```

This works for me but when i try to do this.

```
 savePDF = (page) => {
  this.save(page);
  window.open(`${window.location.pathname}/print`, '_blank');
};
```

It doesn't trigger `this.save()` although it opens the print page.

How can i organize this to make code repeat less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `save` function is returning a new function when you call it like

```
this.save(page);
```

I dont see any need of returning a new function here. You can simply define the function like this and that will work

```
save = (page) => {
  this.props.toggleSaving();
  this.props.savePage(page);
  this.props.toggleSaving();
};
// And then calling it like this will work
this.save(page);
```

Comment: yap -t was not working because i was returning a new function.. thanks...